# Can I hot-deploy to a remote install of Tomcat?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, mobile, eclipse-wtp

Currently, the Tomcat server that I'm using to develop against is localhost - and I'm using Eclipse WTP to hotswap code onto the server.

However, I'm starting to do some mobile development and I'd like to be able to work in the same model - when I change code, it appears on the device.

The snag is, the tomcat instance I have access to via a mobile (i.e. external, 3G access rather than internal connectivity) does not sit on my machine, it sits on another server.

Is there any way I can still do Hotswap (preferably through Eclipse) onto this Tomcat instance that is external to my machine?

Would JRebel do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Note - I know how to package a war and deploy it remotely, but that's not what I'm asking here. I'm trying to use hotdeploy.

Comment: See: [Eclipse on-click deploy to remote Tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254839/eclipse-on-click-deploy-to-remote-tomcat)

Answer (score 2):

You can remotely hot deploy onto Tomcat using Tomcat's manager application. There's a description at the link below. You can then create an Ant script based on this and put it into your build process on Eclipse (I'm reliable informed - I don't actually know how to do this)

[Deploying to Tomcat](http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-deploy)